# Copy paste activates control button for keyboard shortcuts on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ctrl

For two weeks now I have this problem that drives my insanity up - and my productivity doiwn: Whenever I copy paste with CTRL+C / CTRL+V, my computer keyboard behaves as if I had CTRL button pressed for subsequent tasks: rolling mouse wheel will increase-decrease zoom of active window, hitting 'P' will open printing dialogue window, hitting 's' will offer to save... I can reset the computer to normal with CTRL+Escape, but I have to do it every minute or so as I am using CTRL+C very often.

I tried uninstalling keywboard and mouse completely in device manager, then reboot to reinstall. I deactivated Ease of Access completely, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Did you look into "sticky keys"? And did you test with a different keyboard (just to rule out the keyboard)?

Comment: Hi Peter - yes I did look into Sticky keys and made sure that none of the checkboxes is checked for [Make the keyboard easier to use]. I actually bought a new keyboard the other day as I thought CTRL button may be the issue, but the problem persists. Thanks

Comment: Yep - unchecked all. Same result: still entering CTRL mode as if the CTRL button was pushed. P opens print menu, S wants to save, scrolling wheel goes into page zoom mode. 'Evil' would be the right terminology...

Comment: I reviewed all Ease of Access functions and unchecked everything everywhere. The only place that I can change are the radio bvuttons in the section Set up filter keys... has to be one or the other, I have currently 'Turn on Bounce keys' selected. but even if I select the other one, it still does not solve my problem.

Comment: Just noticed that its not just CTRL+*** that will trigger the cahnge of mode - as soon if I hit the CTRL key, it switches the mode!

Comment: @Peter  I am not sure if we found a workaround yet: Whenever I hit CTRL, the problem is back and I have to hit CTLR+Escape to get rid of it.... which happens every 10 seconds :-) This is particularly annoying whan writing an email: imagine doing a CTRL+C to copy info into an emial and then hitting ENTER to go to next line of my message?...yep. Instead of going to the next line, the message gets sent :-(?#%$@((

Comment: nope - only CTRL+Escape buttons does toggl ctrl off. @Peter